# No signal after idling, 21.04

Tags: nvidia, 21.04

I'm new to Linux, and am trying to get Ubuntu to work for me. However, every time the screen goes black due to me being idle, it won't restart. I get a no signal message from my monitor and then just a back screen no matter what I do to my mouse and keyboard. Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to have to keep powering the pc off and on forever every time I leave my pc for 5 minutes.

I have a nvidea GPU (1070) with the proprietory drivers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the idle timer to infinity in the power settings of Ubuntu